# im trying to discplay a certain part of a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

im writing a program for school that takes a file detailing different statistics of a file. I am trying to get this one function in particular working but i cant seem to figure out whats wrong.

[here is the prompt for this specific function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgdnH.png)

[here is the indexing for each of the variables in the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tabl.png)

and here is the code i have written to try and make this work

```
def get_damage_data(data, year):

  year_info = []
  for line in data:
      if line[0] == year:
        tup = (line[1], line[3][:40],line[6],line[7],line[8],line[9])
        year_info.append(tup)
  return (year_info)

def get_quake_data(data, year):

year_info1 = []
for line in data:
    if line[0] == year:
        tup = (line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],line[5])
        year_info1.append(tup)
return (year_info1)

def summary_statistics(data, year_start, year_end):

if year_end < year_start:
    return []
eartquake_count_by_year = [(year, len(get_quake_data(data, year))) for year in range(year_start, year_end + 1)]
damage_count_by_year = [(year, (get_damage_data(data, year)[5])) for year in range(year_start, year_end + 1)]

casualties_by_year = []
for year in range(year_start, year_end + 1):
    quake = get_damage_data(data, year)
    casualties_by_year.append(year)
    casualties_by_year.append(quake[2])
    casualties_by_year.append(quake[3])
    casualties_by_year.append(quake[4])
    
L = [earthquakes_count_by_year,damage_count_by_year,casualties_by_year,]
return (L)
```

i have included the previous two functions as well because they tie into this function.

also id like to mention i got the earthquakes per year to show up in my list but the caualties per year and  the damages part are printing the entire quake_damages function instead of just the 2 values i want them to print

Comment: pls check that typo: eartquake , earthquakes . whether that's causing the trouble ?

Comment: yeah i did that it still doesnt work for me